# Optional wrapping in Swift, why does Swift add the "Optional" to the string

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, word-wrap

I'm saving an array into a model, when saving the data is not wrapped with Optional (...) however when the data is being read I get the Optional(...) wrapping around it. Appreciate your help and patience as I'm new to Swift.

This is the `println` when adding the values to the model:

```
saveOperativesInModel: Test Name
```

This is the `println` when reading the values back from the model:

```
getOperativesFromModel: Optional(Test Name)
```

Why does Swift add the "Optional(xxx)" to the String?

This is the reduced code:

```
func saveOperativesInModel() {


    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Operatives", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    var item: NSManagedObject!
    if let operativesList = self.operativesResult?.operativesList {
        self.operativesTable.removeAll()
        for itemInArray in operativesList {
            item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
            item.setValue(itemInArray.firstName, forKey: "firstName")
            var error: NSError?
            if !managedContext.save(&error) {
            } else {
                self.operativesTable.append(item!)
                println("saveOperativesInModel: \(itemInArray.firstName)")
            }
        }
    }

    let fetchRequest1: NSFetchRequest! = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Operatives")
    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest1, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]
    if let operativesTable = fetchedResults {
        if operativesTable.count > 0 {
            for item in operativesTable {
                let operative: Operative! = Operative()
                operative.firstName = String (stringInterpolationSegment: item.valueForKey("firstName"))
                println("getOperativesFromModel: \(operative.firstName)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Optional` appears in the console because `item.valueForKey` returns an `AnyObject?`, an optional type. Since you're using the `valueForKey` value in your string interpolation segment, that value becomes optional. Therefore, the value being printed to the console is optional, and Swift automatically adds the `Optional()` wrapper around optional values in the console.

To avoid this behavior, you can either:

- Force-unwrap the value from `valueForKey` by using the `!` (force unwrap) operator, which would look something like this: `String(stringInterpolationSegment: item.valueForKey("firstName")!)`, or
- Use `if let` to check for a value and then print out the unwrapped value. For example:

  ```
  if let firstName = item.valueForKey("firstName") {
      operative.firstName = String(firstName)
      println("getOperativesFromModel: \(operative.firstName)")
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks (and for deleting the previous comment :) What is then the solution? Should I wrap it in a way to avoid the Optional() as when I put this array into a TableView I also get the Optional()

Answer (score 2):

It has already been answered *why* you see "Optional(...)" in the output.
Here are some additional thoughts on how so solve the problem.

The reason that you wrote

```
operative.firstName = String (stringInterpolationSegment: item.valueForKey("firstName"))
```

is probably that a direct assignment

```
operative.firstName = item.valueForKey("firstName")
```

does not compile: The rhs has the type `AnyObject?`, whereas the 
lhs is a `String`.

A better solution would be an optional cast

```
if let firstName = item.valueForKey("firstName") as? String {
    operative.firstName = firstName
} else {
    // There is no first name, or it is not a String.
}
```

Or use the nil-coalescing operator `??` to provide a default value:

```
operative.firstName = item.valueForKey("firstName") as? String ?? "default name"
```

**But what I would actually** do is to let Xcode create NSManaged object
subclass files for the Core Data entity (perhaps you even did that
already?). Then you don't need the Key-Value coding methods anymore
and can access the entities properties directly:

```
let fetchRequest1: NSFetchRequest! = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Operatives")
let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest1, error: &error) as? [Operatives]
if let operativesTable = fetchedResults {
    for item in operativesTable {
        let operative = Operative()
        operative.firstName = item.firstName
        println("getOperativesFromModel: \(operative.firstName)")
    }
}
```